# ajax onclick listener doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a page that contains many `li` and each `li` has an onclick listener like this:

```
<?php while ($row = $allFoods->fetch()) { ?>
        <li onclick="selectFood(' <?php echo $row['Name']; ?> ')">
            <?php echo $row['Name']; ?>
        </li>
    <?php } ?>
```

that works good as expected

I have a search button, when the user press it, i want to get data from database using `ajax` and for each data element i want to put it in a `li` and apply the onclick listener to it.
I have worked like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#searchButton").click(function (){
        var foodToSearch = $("#foodToSearch").val();
        $.getJSON("http://localhost/TheEatTel/Food/search/"+foodToSearch+"/TRUE",function(data){
            var results = '';
            for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                results +='<li onclick="selectFood('+ data[i] +')">';
                results+=data[i];
                results+='</li>';
            }
            alert(results);
            $(".afflFoods").html(results);
        });     
    });
});
```

the data is showing good as expected, but the onclick listener is not working , i mean when i press in any new item (that comes from database using ajax) nothing happened, why please ? what is the solution, thanks in advice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can attach listener to `li` with this -

```
$(document).on('click','li.selectFood',function(e){

          // do stuff that you'd do in selectFood()
             selectFood($(this).html());
});
```

For that you need `selectFood` as class applied on each li -

```
    <?php while ($row = $allFoods->fetch()) { ?>
        <li class="selectFood">
            <?php echo $row['Name']; ?>
        </li>
    <?php } ?>
```

That way you don't have to reattach event listener to newly added `li` items from ajax.
In ajax you can simply do -

```
        ....
        for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
            results +='<li class=selectFood>';
            results+=data[i];
            results+='</li>';
        }
        ...
```

Comment: `.on()` was added in jquery 1.7 so make sure you have latest version.

Comment: the onclick lister works, but the `   $(".afflFoods").html(results);` at the end of my code stop working , i mean the data comes from database doesn't appear in the `.afflfoods`, what is the solution

Comment: can put `results` var in console and let me know what it outputs?

Answer (score 2):

You didn't quote the string that you pass to `selectFood`.

```
'<li onclick="selectFood(\''+ data[i] +'\')">';
```

Comment: yes it works , and the onclick lister is working good, but now the `$(".afflFoods").html(results);` stop working , i mean the data comes from database didn't appear in the `.affloods`